# jquery datatables adding row_selected class to a row

Tags: jquery, class, datatables, row

I have got a table which is coming with some data. One of the columns is a combobox holding the year information. When click on the row it is selected automatically. However, when I change the year combo the selection disappears (which is normal). I want the select the row again whenever combo changes. both click function and combo changes function are placed as below:

```
        $("#rulesTable tbody").click(function(event) {

            $(rulesTableGlobal.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){
                $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
            });
            $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');

            var row = getSelectedRowIndex(rulesTableGlobal);
            var selectedYear = $('#comboYear'+ row +' option:selected').text(); 
            var propertyId = rulesTableGlobal.fnGetData()[row][0];

            $('#calendarFrame').attr('src', "propertyTariffCalendar.php?ref="+propertyId+"&year="+selectedYear);
            updateDescription(row, selectedYear);

        });
```

//combo changes, with all my try attemps. non of them is adding the class to the row.

```
        $("#comboYear"+rowNo).change(function () {

            var comboId    = $(this).attr('id');
            var comboIndex = $(this).attr('name');
            var propertyId = rulesTableGlobal.fnGetData()[comboIndex][0];
            var yearSelected = $('#'+comboId+' option:selected').text();

            //alert(comboId + "-" + comboIndex+ "-" + yearSelected+ "-" +propertyId);
            $.fn.upDateRow ( propertyId, yearSelected, comboIndex );
            $('#calendarFrame').attr('src', "propertyTariffCalendar.php?ref="+propertyId+"&year="+yearSelected);

            updateDescription(rowNo, yearSelected);

            /*var orjRow = $(this);
            var row    = orjRow.closest("tr").get(0);
            $().addClass("row_selected");
            */

            var orjRow = $("#comboYear"+rowNo);

            //orjRow.parent().parent().addClass("row_selected");
            //alert($(this).closest("tr").attr('id'));
            //$('td:eq(0)', nRow).addClass('highloadRow');

            //$(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('row_selected');
            //$(this).closest('tr').get(0).addClass('row_selected');
            //$(this).closest('tr').addClass('row_selected');
            //$(this).closest('td').closest('tr').addClass('row_selected');
            //alert($(this).closest("tr").parent());
            //$(this).closest("tr").get(0).addClass("row_selected");
            //$(this).closest("tr").addClass("row_selected");
            //$(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I couldn't completely understand your question, but from what I can get, you want the row (`tr` right?) to be given the class `row_selected` when the user clicks on it, and to remove the class from the other rows. If that is what you want, this piece of wizardry will do :)

```
$('#rulesTable').delegate('tr', 'click', function (e) {
    $(this).addClass('row_selected').siblings().removeClass('row_selected');
    // do other things here...
});
```

Tell me if this is not what you wanted.

Comment: yes this is the one. I will check your answer as well as I will write my answer for the ones suffer from the same problem.thanks a million!!!!

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: this is the modified answer I used based on Shrikant Sharat's answer. Thanks a million again..
'select-one' is used to specify if the clicked element is the combo itself (there 2 types of combo. they are separated as select-one and select-two). Because the target changes depending on the clicked element.

Ozlem.

```
            if(event.target.type == 'select-one') {
                //$(event.target.parentNode.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
                $(event.target.parentNode.parentNode).addClass('row_selected').siblings().removeClass('row_selected');
            }else {
                //$(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
                $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected').siblings().removeClass('row_selected');
            }
```